# Nightwatch browser closes when clicked

Tags: node.js, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

I want to click inside the browser that Nightwatch opens during a test.

But as soon as I click on the browser, the browser closes and nightwatch crashes as a result.

**When you click on the browser it acts like you pressed Ctrl+W to close the browser.**

After the browser closes I get the following error, the same error as when I close the browser normally:

```
Error while running .locateMultipleElements() protocol action: chrome not reachable
```

Middle clicking doesn't close the browser.

Normal clicking and right clicking does close the browser.

However on Ubuntu this works, and clicking the browser doesn't make it close.

I've tried upgrading everything to the latest version (npm/Node.js/Nightwatch/Chrome/Selenium server) but it still doesn't work.

This is my nightwatch config:

```
{
  "src_folders": [
    "tests"
  ],
  "output_folder": "reports",
  "custom_assertions_path": "assertions",
  "custom_commands_path": "commands",
  "live_output": true,
  "parallel_process_delay": 100,
  "end_session_on_fail": true,
  "test_workers": {
    "enabled": true,
    "workers": 4
  },
  "selenium": {
    "start_process": true,
    "server_path": "bin/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar",
    "log_path": "seleniumLog",
    "cli_args": {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver": "bin/chromedriver.exe"
    }
  },
  "test_settings": {
    "default": {
      "launch_url": "http://localhost",
      "selenium_port": 4444,
      "selenium_host": "localhost",
      "silent": true,
      "screenshots": {
        "enabled": true,
        "on_failure": false,
        "on_error": false,
        "path": ""
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "chromeOptions": {
          "w3c": false,
          "args": [
            "--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36; Nightwatch",
            "window-size=1056,772"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the test code (`test.js`):

```
module.exports = {
    'Test': function (browserObj) {
        browserObj
            .url('https://www.google.com/')
            .pause(1000000)
            .end();
    }
};
```

This is the command that runs it:

```
nightwatch tests/test.js
```

Platform:           Windows 10

Nightwatch version: 1.2.4 (latest)

Npm version:        6.9.0

Node.js version:    12.13.0

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by it crashes?  what's the terminal output?

Comment: @king_wayne I've updated my question, it just closes when clicked, as if you pressed Ctrl+W.

Comment: If it works for you on Ubuntu and you're having issues with Windows, dumb question, but are you using the correct driver binary?  Also, are your Chrome browser and Chrome driver versions the same?  If so, what versions are they?  This definitely sounds like an isolated issue with perhaps the Windows driver